# How to use not equal and is null together in where clause in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be964/5

I expect two result.

If table contains the product key such as 'x', it need to get them. 
Otherwise; if table doesn't contain the product key such as 't', it need to get records are null.

I have tried a query like below;

```
declare @param nvarchar(30);
set @param = 'x' -- or 't'
SELECT *  FROM [Test]
WHERE 
([ProductKey] = @param and [ProductKey] is not null) 
or 
([ProductKey] <>@param and [ProductKey] is null)
```

But It doesn't work.

Comment: The "table contains product key 'x'" is a separate query from "get the products that ...". You can't do them both in the same single query because a query revolves around single rows.

Comment: I think you need to declare the scalar variable @param first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the where clause in your select works by-line. you only want the `productkey is null` part when there are no matching product keys if i am not mistaken. i suggest you use the exists function. so when the productkey exists in your table, it uses that or when it does not it uses null:

```
declare @param varchar;
set @param = 'x' -- or 't'


SELECT * FROM [Test]
WHERE ([ProductKey] = @param)
   or ([ProductKey] is null 
       and not exists (select * from [Test] where [ProductKey] = @param))
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. But use in this way would constitute a problem for me ? Is there a better solution ?

Comment: what exactly would be a problem? this is the best and simplest solution i can think of. if you can't use certain code, let me know which and i will think about a workaround

Comment: the first statement in your where clause does nothing except slowing the query: 'exists (select * from [Test] where [ProductKey] = @param) and' can be removed

Comment: @BrettSchneider I thought it would be a problem for performance to use nested select.

Comment: @sinanakyazici: i don't think it can be entirely avoided as the scope of `where` is the single row. you need that scope combined with the scope of the entire table. thanks to @t-clausen.dk one of the exists is now history and performance should have thus improved